# Issues with libfontconfig / libxft-dev

Tags: apt, fonts

I'm having an issue with making LMMS.

I get to this point:

```
Linking CXX executable RemoteZynAddSubFx
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXft
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfontconfig
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [plugins/zynaddsubfx/RemoteZynAddSubFx] Error 1
make[1]: *** [plugins/zynaddsubfx/CMakeFiles/RemoteZynAddSubFx.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

One suggestion was to install libxft-dev which I tried and followed the process below:

```
michael@michael-Lenovo-Z580:~$ sudo apt-get install libxft-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxft-dev : Depends: libfontconfig1-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
michael@michael-Lenovo-Z580:~$ sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfontconfig1-dev : Depends: libfontconfig1 (= 2.10.93-0ubuntu1) but 2.11.0-0ubuntu1~saucy1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
michael@michael-Lenovo-Z580:~$ sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libfontconfig1 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I'm pretty confused. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run these commands on your terminal,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install libxft-dev
```